# How to check the which activity is currently running while debugging the app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-debugging

I am stuck with a project developed by someone else. Its a very big app. So for the purpose of understanding the code I want to know the flow, basically the name of the activity(the java file in the code) which is currently running in on my phone. I can put break-points in all activities, but is there any other way?

Comment: run `adb shell dumpsys activity top`

Answer (score 8):

You can use adb for it.

In your terminal run `adb shell dumpsys activity top`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Super useful for debugging running activities your app launched

Answer (score 5):

Using [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html), you don't need to add handling for all the activities. Do the registration **once**, it works for **ALL** activities, and that is it!

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements
   ActivityLifecycleCallbacks{

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();           
}

@Override
public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
    Log.i("Tracking Activity Stopped", activity.getLocalClassName());

}

@Override
public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
    Log.i("Tracking Activity Started", activity.getLocalClassName());

}

@Override
public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {
    Log.i("Tracking Activity SaveInstanceState", activity.getLocalClassName());
}

@Override
public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
    Log.i("Tracking Activity Resumed", activity.getLocalClassName());
}

@Override
public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    Log.i("Tracking Activity Paused", activity.getLocalClassName());
}

@Override
public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
    Log.i("Tracking Activity Destroyed", activity.getLocalClassName());
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("Tracking Activity Created", activity.getLocalClassName());
    }
}
```

Note that you can identify which activity via **activity.getLocalClassName()**.

Comment: This is not working for me. My application class extends MultiDexApplication, is it because of that?

Comment: You don't have to extends you application class this way. you can use: getApplication().registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(mCallbacks),  see also https://gist.github.com/alexjlockwood/6298122, note the snippet is only an example, you can easily adapt to other use cases!!!

Answer (score 0):

Simple -

In each activity override onStart() method and print log like this -

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("TAG -> ", "YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME");
    }
```

When activity start in your device, it will print log in logcat. Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

From manifest figure out Launching activity and to find out methods and variables used.. u can use "Find Usages" ( Ctrl+G ).

Answer (score 0):

If your application extends  MultiDexApplication class here is a working solution.

In **onCreate()** method of your application class that extends **MultiDexApplication** add the following line to register the callbacks.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new MyActivityLifecycleCallbacks());
}
```

Now make an inner class that implements **ActivityLifecycleCallbacks** as follow

```
private static final class MyActivityLifecycleCallbacks implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
            Log.v("Application","Created");
        }
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
            Log.v("Application","Destroyed");
        }
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
            Log.v("Application","Paused");

        }
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
            Log.v("Application","Resumed");


        }
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {
            Log.v("Application","onActivitySaveInstanceState");
        }
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
            Log.v("Application","Started");
        }
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
            Log.v("Application","Stopped");
        }
    }
```

Now you may use  `activity.getLocalClassName()` in any overridden method you need.

This would be all you need. Happy Debugging :)